# Why does createDataFrame reorder the columns?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose I am creating a data frame from a list without a schema:

```py
data = [Row(c=0, b=1, a=2), Row(c=10, b=11, a=12)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data)
df.show()
```

```
+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|
+---+---+---+
|  2|  1|  0|
| 12| 11| 10|
+---+---+---+
```

Why are the columns reordered in alphabet order ?
Can I preserve the original order of columns without adding a schema ?

Comment: can't you do df.select("a,b,c").show?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why are the columns reordered in alphabet order ?

Because `Row` created with `**kwargs` [sorts the arguments by name](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/d2b8b63b9318710500f5a57bedc418d0c75b1450/python/pyspark/sql/types.py#L1475).

This design choice is required to address the issues described in [PEP 468](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0468/). Please check [SPARK-12467](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-12467) for a discussion.

> Can I preserve the original order of columns without adding a schema ?

Not with `**kwargs`. You can use plain `tuples`:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(0, 1, 2), (10, 11, 12)], ["c", "b", "a"])
```

or `namedtuple`:

```
from collections import namedtuple

CBA = namedtuple("CBA", ["c", "b", "a"])
spark.createDataFrame([CBA(0, 1, 2), CBA(10, 11, 12)])
```