# What a data structure is DataFrame in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

This is a follow-up to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46449404/why-does-createdataframe-reorder-the-columns).
`Row` is an ordered set of key value pairs. `DataFrame` is a collection of `Rows`.
What a data structure is `DataFrame` actually ? Is it a list, set, or other "collection" ? Is it a `relation` as in SQL ?

Comment: Before I try to answer, can I know what makes you think that _"Row is an ordered set of key value pairs."_? Also, when you said _"DataFrame is a collection of Rows."_, didn't you answer your other question _"What a data structure is DataFrame actually ?"_?

Comment: (1) I was wrong saying that Row is an ordered set (see comments in my prev. question) (2) _DataFrame is a collection of Rows_ is not the answer I am looking for. I am looking for a more "theoretical" answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an abstraction  over a `RDD[Row]`, or `Dataset[Row]` in Spark2,  with a defined schema set through a series `Column` classes

> Is it a list, set, or other "collection" ?

Not in Java terms of those words. Similar to how RDD is none of those, but rather a "lazy collection"

> Is it a relation as in SQL ?

You're welcome to run SparkSQL over a Dataframe, but it's a table. Relations are optional

Answer (score 1):

Although Dataframe is an abstraction over RDD, the internal representation of Dataframe is quite different than RDD.

RDD is represented as a JAVA objects and uses JVM for all operations. However Dataframe is represented in tungsten.

Here is an excellent [article](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/04/28/project-tungsten-bringing-spark-closer-to-bare-metal.html) which elaborate how dataframes are represented in tungsten.